# Firebase doesn't update email of Facebook user after Facebook primary email changes

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-login

I have a test Firebase app with Facebook login enabled. I created a test FB account (call it `abc@xyz.com`), logged into Firebase through FB login, requested FB profile data like `id` and `email` through a `GraphRequest` using the `accessToken` returned, and everything seems correct.

Then I added another email to the FB account (call it `def@uvw.com`), changed the primary email from `abc@xyz.com` to `def@uvw.com`, and removed `abc@xyz.com` from the account. So technically, `abc@xyz.com` is now released and not associated with the FB account.

Now when I login to Firebase with `def@uvw.com` Firebase correctly recognizes that it's the same user that logged in before (since FB credentials are the same). However, when I see the users list in the Firebase console, the email of the user still shows `abc@xyz.com`.

So I created a new FB account with `abc@xyz.com` and tried to login to my Firebase app with that. But since I've chosen the "One account per email address" option in Firebase Authentication settings, I get the following error:

```
Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17012 "An account already exists with
the same email address but different sign-in credentials. Sign in using a 
provider associated with this email address." UserInfo=
{error_name=ERROR_ACCOUNT_EXISTS_WITH_DIFFERENT_CREDENTIAL, 
FIRAuthErrorUserInfoEmailKey=abc@xyz.com, NSLocalizedDescription=An 
account already exists with the same email address but different sign-in  
credentials. Sign in using a provider associated with this email address.}
```

This means that even though I've released that email from the FB account, and created a new user with that released email, I can't ever login to my app again (as long as if I've chosen the "One account per email address" option in Firebase Authentication settings)

So I'm curious: is there a reason Firebase doesn't update the email on the first account after the primary email on the FB account changes? Is it a bug? Because the `GraphRequest` response returns the new email, so Firebase should technically be able to update it if there's no other user with the new email already registered.

Comment: any update about this issue? I'm in the same boat...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose Firebase has no idea that the email has changed and can't track it, because Firebase doesn't have permissions to access user's account details, only your app can do this.

You need to manage email change scenario on your own. Here's how I do this on iOS:

1) each time user opens the app I'm doing a Graph API request to fetch fresh user's data. The email returned by this request is compared with the email stored in Firebase for this user.

2) once I detect that the emails are different - I'm updating the email stored in Firebase to be in sync with the Facebook's one. In iOS SDK it is:

```
Auth.auth().currentUser?.updateEmail(to: newEmail) { error in
    // if there was no error - the firebase now has the latest email
}
```

Comment: Interesting. But there's edge cases here. For example, if there's already an old user with the same email (who actually deactivated their FB account after logging in to your app), and now if some new user signs in with that email, you'd have 2 users in your Firebase app with the same email. They're the same user obviously, but it's a weird case.

Comment: @user1056585 This is covered when you link user by Auth.auth().currentUser?.link(with: credential) - firebase would say that an account with email already exists. However, firebase doesn't do this kind of check on sign in via Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) and it is indeed possible to have 2 accounts with same email. Even worse, the credential doesn't have email in it yet. So the only way I see is to retrieve the email via provider's own API and then double-check it manually with firebase using Auth.auth().fetchSignInMethods(forEmail:). I would be happy to hear about a better way if any.

Comment: ... in a few hours after my last comment it appeared that Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) most probably checks for email presence too. Don't know if it was just a temporarily glitch, but I clearly saw Twitter and Facebook accounts both with same email in google console. Now I can't repeat it again, firebase prevents logging with any provider if email already registered.